# Which pixel I have written in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, pixel, opengl-compat

im a begginer using opengl and im working in a mini project.In this project im drawing a line and a polygon and my program needs to decide if this line cuts the polygon.I think that if i know which pixel exactly i have written to make the polygon, i will be able to check if there are the same pixels, the same coordinates of them actually. So my question to you is there any way to find the coordinates of any pixel that i have written?

Im drawing my polygon using this

```
glBegin( GL_LINE_LOOP );
for( unsigned int i = 0; i < sides; ++i ){
        glVertex2f( cos( i * step ), sin( i * step ) );
    }
glEnd();
```

And my point by using this

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2f(px, py);
        glVertex2f(temp, py);
glEnd();
```

I can find the pixels of the line, but can i do the same with my polygon?
I also set the coordinates of my window using gluOrtho2D to [-10,10].

Comment: Is it a requirement to do the test on a pixel basis? Because testing a polygon agains a line is a fairly simple thing to do analytically.

Comment: No ,the test on a pixel basis was my idea! Any other solution is also acceptable.

Comment: Then just test if your line intersects a line of the polygon. A line-line intersection test is, for example, shown [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-line-segments-intersect/)

Comment: Ok thank you i will check it

Comment: Don't use glBegin() and glEnd(). This is deprecated legacy stuff that isn't even supported in the newer versions anymore. If you want to learn how to use OpenGL go for modern OpenGl 4. If you only want to draw some lines without getting too much into low level graphics programming you should probably use a higher level library like sfml or sdl instead.

Comment: I have to use glut libraries

Comment: Also i need to count how many times my line cuts the polygon